# Load data onto an ec2 instance with no associated key-pair (generated by NotebookCloud)

Tags: amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to run iPython notebook in an Amazon ec2 instance (I'm using the free tier, if that makes any difference), using NotebookCloud (https://notebookcloud.appspot.com/) to handle the iPython notebook interface. However, the code I want to run in the notebook needs access to a variety of datafiles and supplemental python files. When NotebookCloud generates a new ec2 instance, it doesn't assign a key-pair to it, and I can't find a way to make it do so. As far as I can tell from other questions, there's no way to SSH into an instance if it doesn't have an associated key-pair. Is there still some sneaky way to get data onto the instance though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. I put the data on an EBS volume and attached it to the instance. Since iPython let's you send commands directly to the operating system by prefacing them with "!", it was then possible to mount the volume on the instance as specified here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html.

Earlier I also tried just enabling x-forwarding and installing a browser on the instance and running ipython notebook in that browser. This, however, proved to be painfully slow, although that might have just been because I was using a micro instance, which I have since decided is not remotely large enough for my task.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using ssh and port forwarding instead of putting the IPython Notebook on the internet or x-forwarding (e.g. `ssh -i prvate_key user@ip_address -L 8889:localhost:8888`)

Point your browser to `http://localhost:8889` for your remote IPython Notebook